# Roots of simultaneous equation in OCTAVE

Tags: octave, gnu

How can I solve:

```
y1 = -x1 + 2*x1^3 + x2
y2 = -x1 - x2               at y1 = 0, y2 = 0
```

I tried this

```
function y = f(x)
y(1) = -x(1) + 2*x(1)^3 + x(2);
y(2) = -x(1) - x(2);
endfunction
fsolve("f", [0;0])
```

and I got

```
x =

   0
   0
```

however correct answer is (0,0), (1,-1), (-1,1) why did I not get other answers?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a quadratic equation.

I am not sure about Octave, but the following code works in MATLAB:

```
syms x1 x2
eqn1= -x1+2.*x1.^3+x2==0;
eqn2= -x1-x2==0;

sol=vpasolve([eqn1,eqn2],[x1,x2],[0,0]);
sol.x1
sol.x2
```

`fsolve` only gives the solution closest to the initial guess.

Comment: the last two lines don't work in Octave 8.3.0, symbolic package 3.1.1.  `"error: @sym/subsref: invalid or nonpublic property 'x1'`.  The output of sol is a 2x1 symbolic matrix [0;0], not a struct with fields x1 and x2 containing all of the solutions

Comment: looking at the package repo, there's at outstanding report about `vpasolve` only returning the primary result (like `fsolve`) that is unlikely to be resolved anytime soon (https://github.com/gnu-octave/symbolic/issues/996). I just created a new issue report about the fact that multi-variate inputs don't return structs (https://github.com/gnu-octave/symbolic/issues/1276).

Answer (score 1):

Another answer suggested `vpasolve` which works in Matlab but not in Octave due to some known incompatibilities (See [Issue #996](https://github.com/gnu-octave/symbolic/issues/996) and [Issue #1276](https://github.com/gnu-octave/symbolic/issues/1276)).  Since you requested an Octave specific answer, the following symbolic approach works in both programs:

```
pkg load symbolic

syms x1 x2

eqn1= -x1+2.*x1.^3+x2==0;

eqn2= -x1-x2==0;

[x1out, x2out] =  solve (eqn1, eqn2, x1, x2)

x1out = (sym 3x1 matrix)

  [-1]
  [  ]
  [1 ]
  [  ]
  [0 ]

x2out = (sym 3x1 matrix)

  [1 ]
  [  ]
  [-1]
  [  ]
  [0 ]
```